# react js push to page from another localhost

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

I have a project developed with nodejs and react js and a button that redirects me to http://localhost:3000/openProblemSetter  with the following code :

```
codeProblem =() => {

  localStorage.setItem('token', null);
  this.props.history.push('/openProblemSetter');
}
```

```
       <Button
         className="button_style"
            variant="contained"
            color="default"
            size="small"
            onClick={this.codeProblem}
          >
            ADD
          </Button>
```

I have another server running that opens http://localhost:8000/OpenProblemSetter

what can I do so the button redirects me to localhost:8000 and not localhost:3000 if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** : You can use `location.assign('url')` to navigate to a new page.

**Method 2** : Or you also can use **Redirect** from React Router routing library. <`Redirect to='url'`/>